# Angular - Use Jasmine to spy on chained methods within HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular-httpclient

I have a situation where I need to spy on a method that is called after another method is called.

Here's the class/method under test:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

  constructor(private customHttpClient: CustomHttpClient) {
  }

    updateSomethingCool(signerVO: SignerVO): Observable<SignerVO> {

    // ...

    return this.customHttpClient.withCustomOverrides(new CustomErrorHandlerHttpInterceptorOverride({ passthroughStatusCodes: [BAD_REQUEST, BAD_GATEWAY] }))
        .put<SignerVO>(`/my/url/goes/here`, signerVO);
    }
}
```

This class uses CustomHttpClient which looks like this:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class CustomHttpClient extends HttpClient {
        private interceptors: HttpInterceptor[] | null = null;

        constructor(private injector: Injector,
            originalHandler: HttpHandler, private originalBackend: HttpBackend) {
            super(originalHandler);
        }

        public withCustomOverrides(...overrides: CustomHttpInterceptorOverride[]): HttpClient {

            // do very customizable things here

            return new CustomDelegatingHttpClient(
                new CustomHttpInterceptingHandler(this.originalBackend, this.interceptors, overrides));
        }
    }

    export class CustomDelegatingHttpClient extends HttpClient {
        constructor(private delegate: HttpHandler) {
            super(delegate);
        }
}
```

Here's my attempt at unit testing that the `put` method has indeed been called, hence I need to spy on the `put` method:

```
describe(SomeService.name, () => {
let service: SomeService;
let customHttpClient: CustomHttpClient;

let emptySignerVO: SignerVO = new SignerVO();

beforeEach(() => {
    customHttpClient= <CustomHttpClient>{};
    customHttpClient.put = () => null;
    customHttpClient.withCustomOverrides = () => null;

    service = new SomeService(customHttpClient);
});

describe('updateSomethingCool', () => {

    it('calls put', () => {
        spyOn(customHttpClient, 'put').and.stub();

        service.updateSomethingCool(emptySignerVO);

        expect(customHttpClient.put).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Now clearly when I run this I receive this failure message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'put' of null
```

However, I do not know exactly how to define either the `put` or `withCustomOverrides` methods in the `beforeEach` portion of the test.

Note that `CustomHttpClient` is simply a customized wrapper class around Angular's `HttpClient` that allows some more detailed functionality.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: In the before each call, remove customhttpclient.put row, you don't need it there, do you still get error then?

Comment: When I remove that line, I receive this error:  `Error: <spyOn> : put() method does not exist
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)`

Comment: Can you add on your post an example how you extend the http-client? I believe your instantiating the service wrong in the test, as it seems customhttpclient is an empty object

Comment: Did you declare a constructor for CustomHttpClient?  If so then you'll want to change the first line of your beforeEach to be `customHttpClient = new CustomHttpClient();` so the result will not be null.  Other thought is that CustomHttpClient perhaps loads an external file, has includes, etc - so your beforeEach() may need have an async() wrapped around it's inside function to allow that to complete.

Comment: @Lucho - I added a bit more context of the cut/mut and also the parent custom class in my question.

Comment: @dmcgrandle - I've added the actual code for the parent custom class.  And yes, there is a constructor there.  I've tried using this as the first line of my `beforeEach()` instead:  `customHttpClient = new CustomHttpClient(injector, originalHandler, originalBackend);` However, I'm still receiving the same error.  I'm not exactly sure what to set those 3 parameters to either since they are abstract classes.

Comment: After some more fiddling I found a solution that was quite easy; please see my answer below.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end I wasn't that far off actually.  The actual test code was fine; the `beforeEach()` method needs updated as follows:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    customHttpClient = <CustomHttpClient>{};
    customHttpClient.put = () => null;
    customHttpClient.withCustomOverrides = () => customHttpClient;

    service = new SomeService(customHttpClient);
});
```

I basically just had to assign the `customHttpClient` object to the `.withCustomOverides` method.

Which, if you look at the flow of the method chaining in the real call, actually makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should inject httpClient ;

```
beforeEach((http: HttpClient) => {
  httpClient = http;
  httpClient.put = () => null;
  httpClient.withCustomOverrides = () => null;
  service = new SomeService(log, httpClient);});
```

Comment: When doing that I receive the following compilation error:

`[ts]
Argument of type '(injectedCustomHttpClient: CustomHttpClient) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(done: DoneFn) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'injectedCustomHttpClient' and 'done' are incompatible.
    Type 'DoneFn' is not assignable to type 'CustomHttpClient'.
      Property 'injector' is missing in type 'DoneFn'.`

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the Angular dependency injection to inject `HttpClient` into `CustomHttpClient`? When testing services that depend on the `HttpClient` you may use the `HttpTestingController`, for a service unit test this might look as follows:

```
it(`should get a new data instance of type T`, 
  async(inject([TestDataService, HttpTestingController],
  (service: TestDataService, backend: HttpTestingController) => {
    // ... tests here
  })
));
```

Comment: `CustomHttpClient` actually extends `HttpClient`.  Will this `HttpTestingController` still work in that case?